# Creating a URL with a method result

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I am trying to create a dynamic URL so that multiple users can use an application on their VM.

I have this method

```
def user_environment
  env = ENV['SERVERNAME']
  return env
end
```

Which will return `environment1` `environment2` for example. I want to use the method to construct a url and then visit that page using a capybara method

```
visit("http://'<%= user_environment %>'.myurl.co.uk")
```

That doesn't work, I have tried

```
visit("http://'#{user_environment}'.myurl.co.uk")
```

But I'm getting mixed up with the syntax here.

At the moment I am getting bad URI errors. How can I fix the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try: `visit("http://#{user_environment}.myurl.co.uk")`